# Where did the Flipendo and Skurge spells come from?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, video-games

In the *Harry Potter* games, there are several spells like Flipendo and Skurge, which I don’t remember seeing in the books or movies.

Were they actually used at any point in the books or movies and I didn’t notice, or do they come from somewhere else? (And if so, where?)

Comment: This is at least two questions.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Agreed. It needs to be split or closed.

Comment: Disagree. Perfectly valid question. Those were just examples of the phenomena. He's not asking about the name of game developer for every known spell.

Comment: As far as I can remember, they weren't used in books or films, and were included in the games as a game mechanic. The first two PC games (which I believe the Gameboy versions were based on) are largely puzzle based, in which knocking items back and so on were important (recall Expelliarmus which, in the books is a disarming spell, but in the games is a shield). That was my reasoning -- game mechanics, and that they were made by the game developers. This is, however, merely my own reasoning. I don't have a source to back it up.

Answer (score 3):

No. I cannot remember where, but I read once that the developers included Flipendo only because they needed a default attack spell. Expelliarmus had not been introduced at this point, and everything else was unsuitable.

Skurge is simply a game mechanic used to solve puzzles.

Comment: *Expelliarmus* was introduced in *Chamber of Secrets*, published in 1998, while the *Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone* video game was released in 2001.

Answer (score 1):

## Skurge is in the video games, but has similar effects to Scourgify.

*Skurge* was used in the Chamber of Secrets video game as a cleaning spell to remove the ectoplasm left behind by ghosts. It’s never mentioned again, but a similar spell with a similar incantation as well exists in the books - Scourgify, which is used to clean.

> “Never mind,’ said Ginny bracingly. ‘Look, we can easily get rid of all this.’ She pulled out her wand. ‘Scourgify!’
>
> The Stinksap vanished.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 10 (Luna Lovegood)*</sup></sub>

In the promotional game “Fantastic Beasts: Cases from the Wizarding World”, the spell *Scourgify* serves a similar function that *Skurge* did in the previous games - it’s used to clean up items that need to be investigated.

## Flipendo is only in the games - it’s not in the 7 books or movies.

No spell with the incantation *Flipendo* is ever used in the seven books or their corresponding movies. It was most likely invented to enable the knocking away of objects, which was a big part of the early games especially.

There are no directly analogous spells to it in the books or movies, either. There are spells cast wordlessly that can send people flying, and Expelliarmus and Stupefy are both simple dueling spells, but there’s nothing analogous to *Flipendo* like *Skurge* is to Scourgify.

Comment: The notoriously unreliable wiki claims that the HBP and DH movies use Flipendo and that it also appears in *Cursed Child* and Pottermore.  I have no idea if any of that is actually true.

Comment: @Kevin The movies show people being sent flying backwards, but no incantation is heard, so it’s not certain what spells were used. Flipendo used to be mentioned on Pottermore, as one of the spells in their dueling club, but isn’t anymore. [Picture of Flipendo in dueling club](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pottermore/images/c/ca/Knockback.png/revision/latest?cb=20120604220719) here.